# Odd factors of $a^2+3b^2$ have this same form, when $\gcd(a,b)=1$

Tags: diophantine-equations

edit: I originally made this post to check my understanding of this proof. Now I understand this is not a good type of question to ask. Despite regretting making this post originally, I would rather fix this proof than delete it if that's ok.

My attempt at a proof of the following statement: odd factors of $a^2+3b^2$ have this same form, when $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

(i) First let us establish that the set $a^2+3b^2$ is closed under multiplication.

$\hspace{2.5cm}$$(a^2+3b^2)(c^2+3d^2)$

$\hspace{2cm}$$=(ac)^2+3(ad)^2+3(bc)^2+9(bd)^2$

$\hspace{2cm}$$=(ac)^2\pm 6abcd+9(bd)^2+3(ad)^2\mp 6abcd+3(bc)^2$

$\hspace{2cm}$$=(ac\pm 3bd)^2+3(ad\mp bc)^2=e^2+3f^2$

(ii) We also need to establish the following:

If $N=a^2+3b^2$ and $p=c^2+3d^2$, $p$ is prime and $p$ divides $N$, then $\frac{N}{p}=u^2+3v^2$ ($N,p\in Z$)

Since $p$ divides $N$, it must divide $Nd^2-pb^2$ and:

$\hspace{2cm}$$Nd^2-pb^2=(a^2+3b^2)d^2-(c^2+3d^2)b^2$

$\hspace{4.5cm}$ $=a^2d^2+3b^2d^2-c^2b^2-3b^2d^2$

$\hspace{4.5cm}$ $=(ad+cb)(ad-cb)$

Therefore $p$ divides either $ad+cb$ or $ad-cb$. Being a prime number, it cannot equal the product. Also if $p=1$ then the case is already proved as $\frac{N}{1}=N$. Now consider the expression $Np$:

$\hspace{2cm}$ $Np = (ac\pm3bd)^2+3(ad\mp bc)^2$ [using the identity from (i)]

Given that $p$ divides one of $(ad\mp bc)$, it must also divide $(ac\pm3bd)$, in other words it must divide both terms of $Np$.

Now we can divide $Np$ by $p^2$ so we have:

$\hspace{2cm}$ $\frac{Np}{p^2}=\frac{(ac\pm3bd)^2}{p^2}+\frac{3(ad\mp bc)^2}{p^2}$

$\hspace{2cm}$ $\frac{N}{p}=\left(\frac{ac\pm3bd}{p}\right)^2+3\left(\frac{ad\mp bc}{p}\right)^2$

This tells us (given the above conditions):

$Np=e^2+3f^2 \implies p$ divides both $e$ and $f$ to give $\frac{N}{p}=g^2+3h^2$

Another way to state this is that if $xp=a^2+3b^2$ then $\frac{xp}{p}=c^2+3d^2$.

---

**Theorem:** Odd factors of $a^2+3b^2$ have this same form, when $\gcd(a,b)=1$

It is enough to prove the statement for odd primes, due to (i).

Assume that we have an integer in the form $a^2+3b^2$ that has some prime factor $p$, where $p>2$, that cannot be written in this same form.

$\therefore pq=a^2+3b^2$, where $q$ is an integer and $q>1$ (otherwise $p=a^2+3b^2$). $q$ can be odd or even. These will be considered as separate cases.

#### Case 1: *q* is even.

If $q$ is even, $a^2+3b^2$ is even, so $a$ and $b$ are either both even or both odd. As we are assuming the minimal case, we can assume $a$ and $b$ are both odd.

let $a=x+y$ and $b=x-y$ where $x$ is even, $y$ is odd. $\hspace{1cm}$($a=x-y$ and $b=x+y$ also works)

$\therefore pq=(x+y)^2+3(x-y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2+3x^2-6xy+3y^2=4x^2-4xy+4y^2=4(x^2-xy+y^2)$

Using the fact that $x^2-xy+y^2=\left(\frac{(x-2y)}{2}\right)^2+3\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2$ and that $x$ is even, we can say that $pq=4(c^2+3d^2)$, where $c$ and $d$ are integers and $c^2+3d^2$ is odd.

So we can produce a smaller odd factor $z$ such that $pz=c^2+3d^2$, and we only need to consider the case where $q$ is odd.

#### Case 2: *q* is odd

As $q$ is odd, $a^2+3b^2$ is odd.

Let $a=xp+r$ and $b=yp+s$ where $|r|,|s|<\frac{p}{2}$

($r$ and $s$ being some remainder after dividing $a$ and $b$ by $p$)

$\therefore pq = (xp+r)^2+3(yp+s)^2$

$\hspace{0.9cm}$$= p(x^2p+2xr+3y^2p+6ys)+r^2+3s^2$

$\therefore p\mid r^2+3s^2$ where $r^2+3s^2$ is less than $p^2$, due to the following:

As $r,s<\frac{p}{2}\implies r^2+3s^2<\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^2+3\left(\frac{p}{2}\right)^2$

$\hspace{4.9cm}$$<\frac{p^2}{4}+\frac{3p^2}{4}$

$\hspace{4.9cm}$$<\frac{4p^2}{4} $

$\hspace{4.9cm}$$< p^2$

Hence, we have $pn=r^2+3s^2$, where $n$ is an integer, $n< p$, and $n$ can be either odd or even. However, due to case 1, we can assume $n$ is odd (or produce a smaller odd factor), and as $n$ is odd, we can repeat the above process for $n$, to produce a smaller odd factor, and so on until we produce a prime $i$ such that $i=k^2+3l^2$ (otherwise we have a contradiction by infinite descent).

We can conclude then that due to (ii) and this process of descent, $n, p$  can be shown to have the form $a^2 +3b^2$.

For example, suppose we had shown that $ni=y^2+3z^2$ and so $n=w^2+3v^2$ due to (ii). Then either $n$ is prime or has odd prime factors $n_1,n_2...$ which we would be able to show have the same form. Then $n$ must be of the same form, and therefore also $p$.

This produces a contradiction as we assumed $p$ was not of the form $a^2+3b^2$.

Therefore all odd factors of $a^2+3b^2$ have this same form.

**References:**

13 lectures on Fermat's Last Theorem, by Ribenboim.

Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$ by Cox

http://fermatslasttheorem.blogspot.com/2005/05/fermats-last-theorem-n-3-a2-3b2.html

[www.mathpages.com/home/kmath009/kmath009.htm](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath009/kmath009.htm)

Comment: I don't get "q cannot be of the form $a^2+3b^2$ due to (i)". What you have proved in (i) is not that if both $A$ and $AB$ are of the form, then $B$ is of the form, but that if both $A$ and $B$ are of the form, then $AB$ is of the form.

Comment: But also if we divide $a^2+3b^2$ by the same form, the result must be of the same form. Isn’t that right? If q is of the same form, then $\frac{a^2+3b^2}{q}$ must have that form.. I can’t see the error sorry but I’m not saying it’s correct, just that I don’t understand the mistake.

Comment: The claim might be true, but is not obvious at least to me. You wrote "due to (i)", but (i) proves only that if both $A$ and $B$ are of the form, then $AB$ is of the form, and (i) does not prove that if $q$ is of the form, then $\frac{a^2+3b^2}{q}\in\mathbb Z$ is of the form.

Comment: I used the logic that if ab=c then c/b=a. And I can't think of a reason it is not applicable.

Comment: In (i), you have proved that if both $A$ and $B$ are of the form, then $AB$ is of the form. However, this does not mean you have proved that every integer of the form can be written as the product of two integers of the form. You have not been able to exclude a possibility that there is an integer which can be written as the product of an integer of the form and an integer not of the form.

Comment: "However, this does not mean you have proved that every integer of the form can be written as the product of two integers of the form." I was not trying to. This is a proof for odd factors only, when gcd(a,b)=1.  "You have not been able to exclude a possibility that there is an integer which can be written as the product of an integer of the form and an integer not of the form. " I don't see what this has to do with the problem. I have to be honest, you are beginning to lose me here. If possible, can you be more specific, maybe give a counter example, or give more detail.

Comment: In Case 1, it follows from $pq=4(x^2-xy+y^2)$ that $q$ has to be divisible by $4$. However, I don't see how you got $q=4$.

Comment: Something clearly wrong with my logic. I made another edit to correct this.

Comment: In Case 2, you have written "Let $a=xp+r$ and $b=yp+s$ where $r,s<\frac{p}{2}$ (r and s being some remainder after dividing a and b by p)" We can say $r,s\le p-1$, but I don't see why you can say $r,s\lt\frac p2$.

Comment: My reasoning is as p is odd, $r,s\neq\frac{p}{2}$ and we can ensure they are less than by changing the factors x and y. also, r and s could be negative, which I believe is fine as we are squaring them.

Comment: If you mean $|r|,|s|\lt\frac p2$, then I agree with you.

Comment: I don't get "$f,n,p$ must all have this same form". Suppose that we have $mi=r^2+3s^2$ with $i\lt m$, and finally have $i=k^2+3l^2$. Then, how do you know that $m$ is of the form $a^2+3b^2$ when you have not proven Claim A written in my answer?

Comment: Yes I’m beginning to understand that I clearly used some bad circular logic here and didn’t prove anything. I sincerely appreciate you taking the time to explain my mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your argument has an error.

You have written

> (i) First let us establish that the set $a^2+3b^2$ is closed under multiplication.
> $\hspace{2.5cm}$$(a^2+3b^2)(c^2+3d^2)$
> $\hspace{2cm}$$=(ac)^2+3(ad)^2+3(bc)^2+9(bd)^2$
> $\hspace{2cm}$$=(ac)^2-6abcd+9(bd)^2+3(ad)^2+6abcd+3(bc)^2$
> $\hspace{2cm}$$=(ac-3bd)^2+3(ad+bc)^2=e^2+3f^2$
> $\hspace{2cm}$This also implies that $\frac{e^2+3f^2}{c^2+3d^2}=a^2+3b^2$

Then, you have written

> q cannot be of the form $a^2+3b^2$

You are saying in the comments that the above argument proves the following claim :

Claim A : If $q$ is of the form $n^2+3m^2$, then $\dfrac{a^2+3b^2}{q}$ is of the form $n^2+3m^2$.

---

I think that you have **not** proven Claim A.

So, I think that you are claiming, without any proof, that $q$ cannot be of the form $a^2+3b^2$.

To see why your argument does not prove Claim A, let us consider the following claim :

Claim B : If $q$ is of the form $n^2+\color{red}7m^2$, then $\dfrac{a^2+\color{red}7b^2}{q}$ is of the form $n^2+\color{red}7m^2$.

The claim B is *false*. A counterexample is $\dfrac{3^2+7\times 7^2}{1^2+7\times 5^2}=2$ where $2$ is not of the form $n^2+7m^2$.

However, using your argument, I can "prove" that Claim B is true as follows :

> First let us establish that the set $a^2+7b^2$ is closed under multiplication.
> $\hspace{2.5cm}$$(a^2+7b^2)(c^2+7d^2)$
> $\hspace{2cm}$$=(ac)^2+7(ad)^2+7(bc)^2+49(bd)^2$
> $\hspace{2cm}$$=(ac)^2-14abcd+49(bd)^2+7(ad)^2+14abcd+7(bc)^2$
> $\hspace{2cm}$$=(ac-7bd)^2+7(ad+bc)^2=e^2+7f^2$
> $\hspace{2cm}$This also implies that $\frac{e^2+7f^2}{c^2+7d^2}=a^2+7b^2$

This shows that your argument does not prove Claim A.

If you want to use that "$q$ is not of the form $n^2+3m^2$", then, for example, you need to prove the following claim :

Claim C : If $a$ is of the form $n^2+3m^2$, and $b$ is not of the form $n^2+3m^2$, then $ab$ is not of the form $n^2+3m^2$.

If you can prove that Claim C is true, then you can say that $q$ cannot be of the form $n^2+3m^2$.

Comment: This is going to take a while to wrap my head around. I just can't seem to understand why this is true, but it clearly is, as you have shown with a counter example. Thank you.