Descent Step for showing p | x^2 + 3y^2 implies p is of the same form
Euler's 'descent method' is well known for the cases where N has the form
$$x^2 + y^2$$ or $$x^2 + 2y^2.$$
We would like to apply the same argument, where we contradict p not being of the same form as N by constructing an infinite sequence of strictly decreasing primes, to the sum of a square and thrice a coprime square's case. The reason we cannot naively apply this is because the descent step fails for 2, so the existence of a q < p where q is not of the form of N does not construct such a sequence, as finding q = 2 prevents us from infinitely iterating. Obviously if N is odd this is no problem, so I'm assuming N is even throughout.
Cox's book Primes of the Form ... offers the following result to help finish the descent.
Division of $$N = x^2 + 3y^2$$ by 4 preserves N being a sum of a square and thrice a coprime square.
The only use of this result I can gather is that we can reduce a given N down to having only one factor of 2.
If we assume, as in the previous cases, that all the odd primes less than p dividing N are each the sum of a square and thrice a coprime square, we reduce down to 2p being the sum of a square and thrice a coprime square, which doesn't strike me as helpful. Consequently, we can't, as in the original proofs, take the contrapositive and construct an infinite sequence.
Ideally, we would like to assume p is not of the form of N and find an odd q with q < p, which would allow us to construct the infinite descent. If this route of proof is possible I'd appreciate some indication of how it runs.

Related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3971145/odd-factors-of-a23b2-have-this-same-form-when-gcda-b-1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370263/prove-that-if-an-odd-prime-p-divides-an-integer-of-the-form-x2-3y2-then. Do you think they answer your question?

However, consider $x^2+3y^2$ modulo $4$. What are the possible values?

Possibilities are 0, 1, 3 mod 4 via quadratic residues, by coprimality of x, y the possibilities become 1 or 3. Upshot: we cannot have an odd power of 2 be the largest power of 2 dividing N because of these congruences. And so we can reduce N to being odd and the descent follows as before. Does this look right?

Yes, that is what I meant. Although, $0$ cannot be ruled out (e.g. $9+3\cdot 1 = 12$), but that is no problem for the argument (why?). (I admit I don't have the full structure of the proof present, so I'll leave it to you to determine if you believe it finishes your proof).
